# Heroku Time out compiling App Nodejs APP error

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I was deploying my first nodjs-express app on heroku but i noted the build process terminated after 15 minitues timeout. below is a screenshot of the error. 
Secondly i noted that heroku is running the nodeapp on port 5000 port yet it should automatically assign me a port. In my nodejs code i defined the port as below.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

Please help on how to go about this problem

[image]

Comment: Create a `Procfile` with the content `web: node server.js`. Only a `web` process has the `PORT` environment variable set.

Comment: I'm also wondering why your project is running `node server.js` during `build`. `build` is for e.g. generating the html/js files. You build the web files with `npm build` locally. You start the project with `npm start`. If you wrote `node server.js` in your `build` located in `package.json` delete that. That should only be in `start`.

Comment: Thanks soo much.

Comment: It worked. and even the build on azure pipelines worked. Thanks

Comment: so one thing i am learning is that i should only use the build script when i have some javascript files i need to compile right?  @TinNguyen

Comment: Correct. What is done there in detail I cannot say. I myself don't fully understand that part. E.g. you develop a single page app using node.js and run the build script so it is available in your browser which does not rely on node.js.

Comment: actually my nodejs app has not front end. it is just a restful api. Thanks